# Creating new column based on values in other columns and a factor variable

Tags: r

I have the following table which contains a factor variable 'category' with two levels DH1 and DH2. I also have interval values for the factor variable 'from' and 'to'.

```
category = c('DH1','DH1','DH1','DH1','DH2','DH2')
from = c(356,366,367,368,401,402)
to = c(366,367,368,369,402,403)

df <- data.frame(category,from, to)

  category from  to
1      DH1  365 366
2      DH1  366 367
3      DH1  367 368
4      DH1  368 369
5      DH2  401 402
6      DH2  402 403
```

I need to create two new columns which may look like this where as soon as DH1 changes to DH2, the from1 starts as 0 and to1 = to-from

```
  category from  to from1 to1
1      DH1  365 366     0   1
2      DH1  366 367     1   2
3      DH1  367 368     2   3
4      DH1  368 369     3   4
5      DH2  401 402     0   1
6      DH2  402 403     1   2
```

I understand that I need to have a for loop and loop through 'category', then have an if statement `category[4] != category[5]` and on the basis of this calculate the new columns. But is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: As soon as DH1 changes to DH2, the from1 starts as 0 and to1 = to-from.

Comment: ... and similarly to @Ronak's question, for the 1st row how is `to1` 1? `to - from` is `366 - 356 = 10`

Comment: @MauritsEvers I fixed that error, my apologies for that! It is a cumulative addition as the second row of to1 equals to the second row of from1 +1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(from1 = row_number() - 1, 
          to1 = cumsum(to - from))


#  category  from    to from1   to1
#  <fct>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 DH1        365   366     0     1
#2 DH1        366   367     1     2
#3 DH1        367   368     2     3
#4 DH1        368   369     3     4
#5 DH2        401   402     0     1
#6 DH2        402   403     1     2
```

For every `category` this assigns `row_number() - 1` value to `from1` and calculates cumulative sum of `to - from` values. If `category` is not ordered and `DH1` can occur again as different group we might need to `group_by` `data.table::rleid(category)`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way using `library(dplyr)`:

```
df %>% arrange(category, from) 
  %>% group_by(category) 
  %>% mutate(from1 = row_number()-1, to1 = row_number())
```

It sorts the data by `category` and `from` and group by the `category` variable to make sure from1 and to1 can be based on row numbers *per category* by using `mutate` function which is used to creates new variables.

Comment: This will work but only in case the intervals are always equal to 1, but sometimes they can be 1.5 or 2. from = 402.5 to = 404.

Comment: marianess, you never showed that as an example. All your input showed counting 0 to n-1 or 1 to n. @Arnaud's answer is entirely correct and explanatory. It's a good answer. Please accept an answer and create a new question with examples that spans all your cases.

Answer (score 1):

If you are numerating 1..n within each category, you can use the "dplyr" package:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(category) %>% mutate(to1=1:n(), from1=to1-1)
```

If you are trying to compare a value in row i with row i+1, you can use the function `lag`, also from "dplyr" (the built-in `lag` function only works on timeseries):

```
dplyr::lag(df$category)
[1] <NA> DH1  DH1  DH1  DH1  DH2 
Levels: DH1 DH2
```

(once you've loaded the "dplyr" package, it will replace the built-in `lag` function and you don't need to call it as I wrote in the example - that was merely to emphasise which function I am referring to)